# Algorithm to implement a higher order fractal

Tags: algorithm, matlab, fractals

I'm trying to make a code for a n-order Koch fractal, defined as:
[image: Koch fractal]
For that, I'm implementing a code in Matlab. I've been able to develop a code that is able to plot a second order fractal (zero and first orders are pretty easy though). For that, I've based the code in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500397/calculate-points-of-koch-curve). Up to now, I've got this, which works, but obviously just for order two (or one and zero, just editing a bit the code)

```
clear all;
clc;
close all;
hold on;
% Counter-clockwise rotation matrix
R = [cosd(60) -sind(60);sind(60) cosd(60)];
angles = [0 60 -60 0 0]; % main angles
n = 2; % order
% Length of each straight segment
seglength = 3^-(n-1);
% Initialization of variables
a=0;
b=0;
c=1/3;
d=0;
for i=1:4^(n-2)
    for j=1:4
    p1 = [a;b];
    p5 = [c;d];
    p2 = (2.*p1+p5)/3;
    p4 = (2.*p5+p1)/3;
    p3 = p2 + R*(p4-p2);
    x = [p1(1) p2(1) p3(1) p4(1) p5(1)];
    y = [p1(2) p2(2) p3(2) p4(2) p5(2)];
    line(x,y);

    a=a+seglength*cosd(angles(j));
    c=c+seglength*cosd(angles(j+1));
    b=b+seglength*sind(angles(j));
    d=d+seglength*sind(angles(j+1));
    end
end
axis equal;
```

I know it is not a clean and optimum code. I'm just interested in any kind of tip that could help me to develop a n-order Koch fractal, just changing the value of n.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Recursion is your friend. Btw. there are several examples already available on the net. Just search for koch curve matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly improve upon your algorithm, specifically taking advantage of vectorization to reduce the computation to a single for loop (and making it easy to extend it to any order). You don't even really need recursion (although that's another option). Here's a vectorized function `koch`:

```
function [x, y] = koch(N, x, y)
  R = [cosd(60) -sind(60); sind(60) cosd(60)];
  x = x(:).';
  y = y(:).';
  for iOrder = 1:N  % Loop N times
    x1 = x(1:(end-1));
    x5 = x(2:end);
    x2 = (2.*x1+x5)./3;
    x4 = (x1+2.*x5)./3;
    y1 = y(1:(end-1));
    y5 = y(2:end);
    y2 = (2.*y1+y5)./3;
    y4 = (y1+2.*y5)./3;
    temp = R*[x4-x2; y4-y2];
    x = [x1; x2; x2+temp(1, :); x4];
    y = [y1; y2; y2+temp(2, :); y4];
    x = [x(:).' x5(end)];
    y = [y(:).' y5(end)];
  end
end
```

For a set of `M` points (both `x` and `y`) at each iteration, the starting points for each line are given by `x(1:(M-1))` and the ending points are given by `x(2:M)`. You can interleave your 3 new points in between these by building a 4-by-`M-1` matrix where the top row is your starting points and each successive row is one of your 3 new points (computed as in your link). Reshaping the resulting matrix with `(:).'` (and adding the very last end point) will give you a 1-by-`4*M-3` set of points for the line, which can be used by the next iteration.

And here's the code in action:

```
[x, y] = koch(0, [0 1], [0 0]);
plot(x, y);
axis equal;
hold on;
[x, y] = koch(1, x, y);  % or [x, y] = koch(1, [0 1], [0 0]);
plot(x, y);
[x, y] = koch(1, x, y);  % or [x, y] = koch(2, [0 1], [0 0]);
plot(x, y);
[x, y] = koch(1, x, y);  % or [x, y] = koch(3, [0 1], [0 0]);
plot(x, y);
legend({'0' '1' '2' '3'});
```

[image]

Notice you can get an `n`<sup>th</sup> order fractal by either passing `n` and your starting points or passing `1` and the points for the `n-1`<sup>th</sup> fractal.

Comment: That was really helpful! I thought about the interpolation of points, but was not sure about howq to implement it. Thanks for such a helpful answer! @gnovice

Comment: @Zarauztarra: I made an improvement. I was creating redundant points in the line with the previous version. This newer version takes those out.

Comment: Woah that's really nice. I've checked the edit and realized about that too. Thanks for changing it!